# How to hide previous CellImage when a new cell is clicked in iOS app

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I am showing a image in CellImage when any cell is clicked it works fine but problem is that when a new cell is selected then previous cell image is also visible i want that when user selects on new cell previous cellImage should be hidden.

here is the code

```
-(IBAction)imageButtonAction:(id)sender{

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [[sender superview] superview];
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
UIView *backimage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,0,312,105)];
backimage.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popupj.png"]];
[backimage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell addSubview:backimage];
}
```

I am calling this method on the button which is in cell i have used custom cell

[image: here is the screen shot of the image]

Comment: After you adding `backimage` in cell, it was not removed anywhere and you are not keeping any reference for this. BTW, what exactly u want? Cud u please explain a little bit more to get it clear.

Comment: can u elaborate more and if possible post image of UI that u are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes i am not removing it i want that when cell is clicked it should add this backImage and when new cell is clicked previous should be removed and new should be added but using following it show two backImage one for one selected then you select second then second for that

Comment: @iLearner here is the link for image http://imageshack.us/f/546/tlpg.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this, it may help you.

```
-(IBAction)imageButtonAction:(id)sender{

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [[sender superview] superview];
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    for (UIView *subView in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){
            subView.hidden=YES;
        }
    }
    UIView *backimage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,0,312,105)];
    backimage.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popupj.png"]];
    [backimage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell addSubview:backimage];
}
```

Or you can even use the block, to loop through subviews and hide them

Cheers

Comment: using this code it does not hide the backImage but hides other cell text

Comment: @JanDeveloper, Alright..In that case you can even set the tag for your view and then hide accordingly.Hiding subview with the previous tag and then you don't even need to loop..
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is a value on a table view xib called selection, check that its value is set to single selection in your xib. Or programmatically set this property to NO:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL allowsMultipleSelection
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button action you could set maintain the **previousIndexPath** which should be declared in the .h file . By using this previousIndexPath you can easily hide the previously loaded image:

```
      CustomCell *cell=(CustomCell *)[yourTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousIndexPath];
      cell.yourImage.hidden=TRUE;
```

Comment: @JanDeveloper: as I mentioned have you declared it in .h file . NSIndexPath *previousIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Change the hidden value property of your previous selected cell in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
Access the cell by using:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousIndex];
cell.yourImage.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: How your answer is different from mine ? isn't it copy paste stuff ?

Comment: @AnuragK how to get previous index